# Create new instance from array of objects in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular app i tried to get a new instance from array of objects to make some changes in value in some object my array like that:

```
invoiceItems = [ 

 {id: 2028, name: "22", qty: 50, buyPrice: 18, salePice: 22, …},
 {id: 1017, name: "item 2", qty: 30, buyPrice: 25, salePice: 30, …},
 {id: 1002, name: "item 1", qty: 20, buyPrice: 22, salePice: 27, …},
]
```

i want to make a new instance like the same this one after take new value for some property

to be the new array like that:

```
newInvoiceItems = [
{id: 2028, name: "22", qty: 70, buyPrice: 20, salePice: 22, …},
 {id: 1017, name: "item 2", qty: 30, buyPrice: 25, salePice: 30, …},
 {id: 1002, name: "item 1", qty: 20, buyPrice: 22, salePice: 27, …},
```

but the problem is the first array also changed by new value. 
forgiv me becuse im still lerning and i hope to fine some help 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objects and arrays are passed by reference in javaScript / typeScript
so if you update the array somewhere, it will be updated in the other place

you need to take a copy of the original array before updating

here are a couple of method you can use to take a copy of some array
1- using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` method

```
let snapshotOfMyArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

2- using the `map` function

```
let snapshotOfMyArray = myArray.map(item => ({ ...item }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
let newInvoiceItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(invoiceItems))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//ES6
const clone = [...myArray];
```

It should be noted that spread only works one level deep so won't work for multidimensional array